# How to clear input field after I run my function in Angular

Tags: angular

I dont know how to clear my two input field after I run my function. I am using model constructor to feed and add data into app. I am new to angular so if someone can show me the way to reset input fields... this is the code

help is very much appreciated

DATA MODEL

```
export class Model {

    items;

    constructor() {

    this.items = [new TodoItem("Buy Flowers", '3days', false),
    new TodoItem("Get Shoes", '1days', false),
    new TodoItem("Collect Tickets", '5days', false),
    new TodoItem("Call Joe", 'today', false)]

}
}
    export class TodoItem {

        action;
        time;
        done;

        constructor(action, time, done) {
        this.action = action;
        this.time = time;
        this.done = done;

        }
        }
```

COMPONENT

```
title = 'Welcome';
  model = new Model();
  todoText;

  getItems(){
    return this.model.items;
  }

  delItems(){
    this.model.items =  this.model.items.filter(item => !item.done)

    }

    addItem(newItem, time) {
      if (newItem != "") {
      this.model.items.push(new TodoItem(newItem, time, false));
```

AND TEMPLATE

```
<h1>
  {{title}}!
  </h1>
  <input class="form-control" #todoText />
  <input class="form-control" #timeText />
  <button class="btn btn-primary m-t-1" (click)="addItem(todoText.value, timeText.value)">
  AddItem
  </button>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr><th></th><th>Description</th><th>Done</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of getItems(); let i = index" >
    <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.action }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.time }}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.done" /></td>
    <td [ngSwitch]="item.done">
    <span *ngSwitchCase="true">Yes</span>
    <span *ngSwitchDefault>No</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table> 
    <button (click)='delItems()'>Remove</button>
```

Comment: Why don't you use just [(ngModel)] for the input?

Comment: I use inputs to get the data and pass it as arguments to a function for add objects into array colection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Compponent:

```
todoText:string='';
timeText:string='';

 addItem(newItem, time) {
    if (newItem != "") {
      this.model.items.push(new TodoItem(newItem, time, false));
    }
    this.todoText='';
    this.timeText=''
}
```

In your html

```
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="todoText" />
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="timeText" />
<button class="btn btn-primary m-t-1" (click)="addItem(todoText, timeText)">
   AddItem
</button>
```

Comment: This clears the inputs but now I dont geting my object property values in my list

Comment: @MarkoC Which part is not working? this.model.items.push or new TodoItem(newItem, time, false) ? Edit: ok